# Is there an idiom for saying that X is worrying you?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom for saying that X is worrying you? I am looking for an idiom that means that an idea is worrying you, but if there's no such idiom I would like to have a phrase with a phrasal verb.

Comment: What's wrong with "I'm worried about X"? If there is some more nuanced meaning you're after, you'll have to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example sentence giving a clearer sense of what kind of "idea" you have in mind as the subject of the phrasal verb would make this question easier to answer, but possibilities include "x is weighing on my mind," "x is preying on my mind," and "x is nagging at me."

Comment: Those are actually really good ones.

Comment: Oh, good! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm worried about X" is the most natural expression.

> I'm worried about my daughter. She spends all her time studying. Shouldn't she be out having fun, or trying to change the world?